# for each loop is not working in major browsers except firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-9

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for each ( var movie in ['Endhiran The Robot','Shivaji The Boss','Anbulla Rajinikanth'] )
    document.writeln(movies + "<br/>");
</script>
```

In Firefox, I am getting the output as

```
Endhiran The Robot
Shivaji The Boss
Anbulla Rajinikanth
```

But in `IE9` and `Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 m`, `for each` is not working and nothing is written on the document

Comment: `for each` should be just `for`

Comment: btw, the var `movies` should be `movie`, right? and you should not use `document.writeln`/`document.write` at all

Comment: @TimBüthe, Thanks. I will be editing and change to `movie`. One doubt, I used `for` alone instead of `for each` but the `output` I am getting as `0,1,2` instead of those `movie names`

Comment: Yeah, right, that iterates over the index, forgot that. I would suggest to just go with Julien Royer's answer.

Comment: @TimBüthe, Thanks. I am going with the Julien Royer's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `for each` in JavaScript, that was a non-standard extension.

There is the new [ES5 `forEach` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18), which is well supported in modern browsers although of course not in older ones:

```
['Endhiran The Robot','Shivaji The Boss','Anbulla Rajinikanth'].forEach(function(movie) {
    document.writeln(movie + "<br/>");
});
```

Several other options over in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery/3943526#3943526) here on Stack Overflow. (The question mentions jQuery, but the answer covers both plain JavaScript and jQuery options.)

Comment: Actually, `for each` was in fact a standard extension.  It's part of the ECMA-357 standard.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: Interesting! But 357 -- ECMAScript for XML -- is not [262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). ;-)

Comment: Sure.  I didn't say it was part of ECMA-262.  I simply said it was following a published standard extending ECMA-262.  ;)

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: Indeed. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The `for each` construction is an extension to the ECMAScript language; it is defined in the E4X specification which is not widely supported.

I think that only Firefox supports it in the HTML scripting microcosm, and it has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

To iterate over an array, you can use a plain `for` loop:

```
var movies = ['Endhiran The Robot', 'Shivaji The Boss', 'Anbulla Rajinikanth'];
for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; ++i) {
  document.writeln(movies[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: So, `firefox` alone is allowing `for each` construction.