# Switch case as string

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    createForm("text,password",".content");
});

function createForm(types,object){
    typ = types.split(',');
    
    //var source = "";
    
    $.each(typ,function(){
        switch(this) {
            case "text":
                console.log('text');
                break;
            default:
                console.log('default');
                break;
        }
    });
    //$(object).html(source);
}
```

I have this code an in console it return 2xdefaults. Why?

I try to return a input for each type as text or password but my switch does not recognize the "typ"

Comment: Use `var` for variable initialisation!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is that `this` within the `each` call is a `String` object instance, not a string primitive. JavaScript has both. In a `switch` statement, the comparison with the cases is via `===`, and a string *instance* is not `===` to a string *primitive*.

Three ways to fix it:

1. If you change your switch to:

   ```
   switch (String(this)) {
   ```

   ...that will turn it back into a primitive, whereupon your `switch` works.
2. As [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) points out in the comments below, use the arguments that `$.each` passes (each string — as a primitive — will be provided as the second argument):

   ```
   $.each(typ, function(index, value) {
       switch (value) {
           // ...
       }
   });
   ```
3. Use any of [the alternatives discussed in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery/3943526#3943526) (one of which is a nice simple `for` loop).

---

Side note: You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring your `typ` variable.

Comment: Agree with VisioN. Why people use jQuery `each()` instead of a native JavaScript loop I'll never know!

Comment: @hohner: Yeah, I lean toward simple loops too, and the signature of the iteration function `$.each` requires is, um, special. :-) A lot of people like the fact that using an iteration function gives them a new scope for iteration-specific variables. That usually indicates (to me) that the function the loop is in is already too complex and needs breaking up, but that's one reason people use it. Before too long they'll be able to use `forEach` reliably for that instead (which does the rational thing of giving the entry as the *first* argument).

Answer (score 9):

jQuery is overkill here, for a correct way to do it with jQuery anyway have a look at T.J. Crowders answer.

I recommend a method that is way simpler by using a standard `for`-loop. It works fine:

```
var types = "text,password".split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    switch(types[i]){
        case "text":
            console.log('text');
        break;
        default: 
            console.log('default');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though TimWolla didn't find the right problem I agree that **for** is better for this purpose. I hate the way people produce unefective codes theese days.

Answer (score 6):

You use the `$.each` function wrongly. It should look like this:

```
$.each( typ, function( key, value ) {
    switch(value){

       case "text":
            console.log('text');break;
       default:
            console.log('default');break;
    }
});
```

Comment: He's not using it *wrong*, but `this` isn't turning out to be what he expects (although it's close).

Comment: I'm sorry, what you say turned completelly true after I looked up docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `switch(String(this))` instead of `switch(this)`. And of course, initialize your variables.