# How to read each element of an array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this

```
var ids = [
  liRightSkills, liRightAchievements, liRightGetRatings, liRightSpecialization, liRightOrgChart, liRightMemberships
];
```

How do I read each element of this using jQuery?

I have tried this but it's not working

```
jQuery.each(ids, function() {
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html ... `.val` is a jQuery method for reading the value of form controls. It helps to have a basic understanding of JavaScript before you do anything with jQuery. Also, this has nothing to do with JSON or Java.

Comment: _Why_ is it not working? What part is not working about what you tried?  Did you try to even google it?

Comment: there are 100's of posts on SO and many many more on web how to loop over an array with jQuery. Even the **[jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** docs have examples

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through array in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In javascript

```
for (i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    alert(ids[i]);
}
```

In jQuery

```
$.each(ids, function(index, value) {
  alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```