# Brightcove, renditions, API

Tags: api, video, brightcove

I have been trying to call the renditions call back for the brightcove media API using the innerHTML = renditions.  If I look into the console of the page it is making the call and giving me an array of each rendition.  In my page where I call upon it though it returns [object Object] for each rendition and the FLVURL nor anything I can find will return the arrays in a http form or anyother type.  Does anyone have any advise.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a brightcove question.  What does your code look like on your page where you actually call to the results?

Comment: document.getElementById('divMeta.render').innerHTML = v.renditions;     This is the call that I make, this call shows me (object, Object) and if i add ".length" to the end it will give me 6, which is the number of renditions each video contains.

Comment: sounds like you need to loop through the array and write each rendition one at at time (v.renditions is an array)

Comment: I am pretty new at this entire process, do you have any recommendations on how I would "loop" through the array?  Im not sure I understand how to do it one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php it might look like:

```
   foreach ($bc_video->renditions as $rendition){
      echo $rendition->url;
          ...
         }
```

to do this in jquery, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery) might help.