# Iterating over an string-based array with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var veeCountries = ["America", "Japan"];

  $.each(veeCountries, function( ? ) {
    $("#content").html("<p>" + value + "</p>");
  });
});
```

I'm trying to output something like this:

```
<p>America</p>
<p>Japan</p>
```

But I'm stuck, what's the best and easiest way of doing this?

Comment: first of all `"<p>" + value + "</p"` to `"<p>" + value + "</p>"`

Comment: this should be marked as **duplicate**....

Comment: @pilot - then hit close and mark it as duplicate so we can see the duplicate ?

Comment: @adeneo..question is about `?` in `function( ? )` . Here is  [How to loop through array in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost literally the same as the example in the docs on $.each(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
$.each(veeCountries, function(index, value) {
   $("#content").append("<p>" + value + "</p>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `each` method passes the index and the actual item of the array to the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var veeCountries = ["America", "Japan"];

  $.each(veeCountries, function(index, item) {
    $("#content").append("<p>" + item + "</p");
  });
});
```

Read the docs at [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 2):

The arguments for `.each()` if the index and the native DOM element, but using `html()` you're overwriting the content on each iteration.
Use `append()` inside the loop, or create the string in the loop and pass it to `html()` once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var veeCountries = ["America", "Japan"],
      output       = '';

  $.each(veeCountries, function( index, value ) {
      output += "<p>" + value + "</p>");
  });

  $("#content").html(output);

});
```

or a little neater

```
$("#content").html('<p>' + veeCountries.join('</p><p>') + '</p>');
```