# Read JSON data values by keys in $.each loop

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I've returned JSON data from controller (via ajax), and wanna access to this data. This is a list of objects (array): key - value, so I wanna use .each() to access all data. Array like that:

```
[{"filePath":"Desktop.zip","fileStatus":"Uploaded"},{"filePath":"Desktop\\dates.xml","fileStatus":"Uploaded"}]
```

and code is:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetFilesNames", "Home")',
                    type: 'POST',                    
                    success: function (data) {                      

                        $.each(data, function (value) {
                            console.log(value['filePath'], value['fileStatus']);

                            });
                    }
                });
```

[image: First picture, data isn't loaded]

But data.each value is undefined.

So I've tried to console.log all data, json.stringify it, parse it (but somehow with error), and parse stringyfied version, but in makes no sense. Even If I use this stringified version (paths) or parsed stringified version (listOfFiles) with .each - same result: undefined.

[image]

Comment: At the top of your `success` function, `data` is an array. That is what you want. **Don't** try converting it to JSON (which isn't useful) or from JSON (because it isn't JSON).

Comment: @Quentin ok, I get it. But if I have an array, so what should I do to get data value by it's key? Why my code 
`$.each(data, function (value) {
                            console.log(value['filePath'], value['fileStatus']);
                            });`
isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through array in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation for `jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> callback
>    Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )

Now see your code:

> ```
> $.each(data, function (value) {
> ```

You are trying to read the properties from the **first** argument, which is an **Integer** (the index in the array() and not the value. You need to be reading properties from the **second** argument.

```
 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
```

Comment: HOLY COW... now I get it.. It's working! Thanks ! Feel so dumb now